# Loop through Object in ArrayList in java

Tags: java

I have a class Budget (Contains Title and Date properties) and an Array which contains objects for this array. I want to iterate through each object to find a matching string. Every time I run this , It's printing not found. Thank You in advance

```
ArrayList<Budget> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Budget>();
public void removeBudget()
{
    String title;
    int indexNumber;
    System.out.println("Enter the Title to be removed");
    title = scanner.next();
    indexNumber = findId(title);
    if(indexNumber != 0)
    {
        myArrayList.remove(indexNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
}
private int findId(String findTitle)
{
    for(int i=0; i<myArrayList.size();i++)
    {
        if(myArrayList.get(i).getTitle().contains(findTitle))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you considered the possibility that there is no match? or that it 's at index 0?

Comment: Well, that suggests that the title just couldn't be found - what is the data involved? How sure are you that the title you're trying to find *does* exist? Have you debugged into the code? If you could produce a [mcve] it would be easier to help.

Comment: Stultuske's point about index 0 is an important one - consider returning -1 if the entry isn't found, instead of 0.

Comment: Start with returning -1 as value for "not found", since 0 is a valid index

Comment: I have tried to match with objects in index 2 and 3 and still its not working

Comment: @AdarshJayakumar have you debugged and checked whether the values you think are being checked are being checked? anyway, if there's also a match at index 0, that's the first encounter, and it will return 0

Comment: Full source code http://pastebin.com/QeBbz1e1

Comment: if you're using eclipse just debug the line `if(myArrayList.get(i).getTitle().contains(findTitle))` and you'll see whats wrong, otherwise you can just print `myArrayList.get(i).getTitle()` and `findTitle` to the console

Comment: myArrayList.get(i).getTitle() contains the string I want . But i don't understand why its not matching with the string I pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the conditioning loop fixed the issue

```
if(indexNumber >= 0)
    {
        myArrayList.remove(indexNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Stultuske said "have you considered the possibility that there is no match?" and

Source code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SO36350049 {
    private class Budget {
        private String title;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SO36350049 so36350049 = new SO36350049();

        Budget budget1 = so36350049.new Budget();
        budget1.setTitle("Budget 1");

        Budget budget2 = so36350049.new Budget();
        budget2.setTitle("Budget 2");

        List<Budget> budgetList = new ArrayList<Budget>();
        budgetList.add(budget1);
        budgetList.add(budget2);

        int index = findId(budgetList, "Budget 1");
        if(index != -1){
          budgetList.remove(index);
        }
        System.out.println(budgetList.size());
    }

    private static int findId(List<Budget> budgetList, String findTitle) {
        for (int i = 0; i < budgetList.size(); i++) {
            if (budgetList.get(i).getTitle().contains(findTitle)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        // If you return `0` it'll remove the element at 0th position
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you missed the other ovious one: don't return 0 for "not-found", since, if the element is found at index 0, ... 
change the "not-found" value, both in the method, and the check afterwards to a negative value.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If you change the condition to `i < budgetList.size() - 1` you will not be checking the last element in the list.

Comment: @Alderath True I guess it shouldn't be -1 because I am getting ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException now

Comment: @AdarshJayakumar Changing that to -1 could not cause ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException. That must be some other issue. At which line of code do you get that exception?

Comment: @Alderath @Adarsh Jayakumar Correct its incorrect answer I ran into different thing that caused exception so I thought you may facing issue. there is error in my code. its after creating object `budget2` I set value in object `budget1` and also you have correct loop

Comment: @Alderath  I am getting exception at  `myArrayList.remove(indexNumber);`

Comment: @VickyThakor Thanks for your answer. I have been stuck with this issue for a long time